# jQuery thickbox not saving data

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery thickbox to popup a window to add records when I click on an add link. It pops up the window but doesn't add the records to database. Although when I directly access this page to add records, it's working fine.

But in popup window it's not same for add and edit. When I click on save button, the popup window hides and I am not able to see what the problem with this page. I also want that this window will not be hidden when I click on `save` button.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: publish some code where you stuck

Comment: <a href="addemployers.php?height=400&width=340" class="thickbox" title="Add Employers">ADD</a>

Comment: this link is on my parent window and on click this link child popup window opens with my form but when i click save button it hides the window and the record doesn't added. That adding record page is working fine alone.

Comment: why it's not inserting the records? i can't echo the result anywhere because when i click save it hides the window and do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented something similar to what you looking for..Hope this helps.
 Firstly,I called a page(suppose record.pl) in POPUP using thickbox using this code in      main.pl.

```
main.pl code:
 print'<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/thickbox.js"></script>
<link href="/stylesheets/thickbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';

 print '<a href="record.pl?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=400&width=600 
 class="thickbox" >Add new record</a>';


record.pl code:
    print $cgi->startform(-method=>'POST', -action=>'database.pl');
              --------------------------------------
     print $cgi->endform;
 database.pl code:
        $record_value=$q->param('record');
                Now make the connection to ur database.
              eg. $connect = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw);
                 and make the query something like 
              e.g $myquery=Insert INTO $tablename VALUES(............);
                 $query=$connect->prepare($myquery);
             $query->execute();
```

It worked for me..Hope this works for you too ..Happy Coding !!

Answer (score 0):

I was also having same kind of problem while using [Facebox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/). Using Ajax submit in my page which opens in popup solves the problem. Now the popup windows stays there even after submitting the form. I hope this will also work for you. Follow the [link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/) on how to submit the form using ajax and jquery.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother.I am going to try this.